# Microsoft Update with Importing Excel Files

Tags: c#, asp.net, excel, hosting

I have an Asp.Net site web who use SqlServer Database . I use Excel files To import data to my database tables ,every Thing is working fine until now it just stop working with this error "Unexpected error from external database driver (1)".
I know that this problem is caused by a Microsoft Update in  10 Oct . and 
 i'm already seen a solution for that problem but in my case my application is on the server , so i cant do much

Comment: Welcome to SO; this question doesn't really ask a question - it just makes a set of statements. It's also likely too broad/imprecise to be a good fit for SO.. Consider editing it to add some detail, the code that does the importing, the line of code that throws the error, the exact error messages/stack traces, and most importantly, what you've tried/what help you need now

Comment: And if you cannot apply the solutions explained in many links how do you think that we can help you? Wait for the patch from Microsoft. It is all that I can tell you then.

Comment: Thanks yes you right i have no problem of waiting for Microsoft . but my clients are using this function a lot so i just hoping for a solution to work around this problem or any idea

Comment: As explained in the links you need to switch your program to use ACE.OleDb.12.0 (or 16.0) if you don't have these drivers installed on your server then you need to install them. Or ask your ISP how to do that on your server. It is a mess I know but....

Comment: That's the thing . I try to use Ace.OLEDB.12.0 and it's not working ,I think it's not installed  ,and i cant install any thing because I'm using a Web Hosting  So it's a real mess :)